# Issue with PlotCurveItem and SetLogMode

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I tried to implement clickable multiple plot with logarithmic scale.
Because I want to the plots clickable, I used PlotCurveItem() and addItem rather than just use plot(). But unfortunatolly, if I used SetLogMode with PlotCurveItem(), the x-axis and y-axis will have almost infinite values (And in reality, [it is not displayed in logarithmic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXeig.png)). When I use [plot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMiKI.png) such problem doesn't happen.

Any solution? or Do you know other good way to implement clickable multiple plot with logarithmic scale? Thanks.

```
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
w.resize(800,800)

p1 = w.addPlot(0, 0, title="p1")
p1.setLogMode(True,True)

temp_curve = pg.PlotCurveItem(y=2*x,
                              pen=pg.mkPen(pg.mkColor(str(color[0]))),
                              width=4, clickable=True)

temp_curve2 = pg.PlotCurveItem(y=3*x,
                              pen=pg.mkPen(pg.mkColor(str(color[1]))),
                              width=4, clickable=True)

p1.addItem(temp_curve)
p1.addItem(temp_curve2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problems and Solutions

There a lot of problems here.

**Problem**

- When you change the scale of the `Plot` widget, it doesn´t update the data on the `PlotCurveItem`. Then you have the same curve but with a wrong axis scale. It works when you use `plot()` because it creates a `PlotDataItem` instead of a `PlotCurveItem`, below I will explain a little more about that.

**Solution 1** (not convenient)

- Create a function like the `getData()` inside the [PlotDataItem's doc.](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/PlotDataItem.html?highlight=getData#) to get the data, transform it to log/linear mode, and then set the data again into the `PlotCurveItem` every time you change the scale. This can be messy.

**Solution 2** (More convenient)

- You can use the `PlotDataItem` instead because it generates a `PlotCurveItem` as part of it (read this: [PlotCurveItem's doc.](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/plotcurveitem.html) and [PlotDataItem's doc.](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/plotdataitem.html)). This `PlotDataItem` updates the data of the plot when you change the scale. Because that is how it works. If you want to know how the changes of scale work I suggest to read the [PlotDataItem's source code](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/PlotDataItem.htm). Implementing this you can create your plots using:

```py
curve_1 = pg.PlotDataItem(
    x, y1, pen=pg.mkPen(pg.mkColor((70,70,30))),
    width=4 # , clickable = True   <-- This don't work
    )
curve_2 = pg.PlotDataItem(
    x, y2, pen=pg.mkPen(pg.mkColor((70,70,70))),
    width=4 # , clickable = True   <-- This don't work
    )
```

**Problem of Solution 2** (and its solution)

- Now a new problem arises, this `PlotDataItem` has a little error. It has the signals when it's clicked, but never activates the "clickable" property of the `PlotCurveItem` created inside it. This will cause you to never get a response when you click on the plot despite you pass the `clickable = True` argument.
- We can do a lot of things to solve this problem, the best and the general solution will implicate a big rework in the `__init__()` builder of `PlotDataItem()`. But considering that you want to implement **clickable** multiple plots with a logarithmic scale, we can just force it to be clickable. To do this we have to set the clickable property of the curve item inside the PlotDataItem with this:

```py
curve_1.curve.setClickable(True)
curve_2.curve.setClickable(True)
```

- Now you can connect the signal emited (`sigClicked`) by the `PlotCurveItem` when it is clicked like this:

```py
curve_1.sigClicked.connect(curve_1_clicked)
curve_2.sigClicked.connect(curve_2_clicked)

def curve_1_clicked(ev):
    print('Curve 1 clicked')
    ## Do more things...

def curve_1_clicked(ev):
    print('Curve 2 clicked')
    ## Do more things...
```

I tested it with a code different from yours, using the `PlotWidget` and using objects to build the GUI, but it must work the same. Here is my code:

```py
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(lay)
        self.glw = pg.PlotWidget(show=True)
        lay.addWidget(self.glw)
        x = np.arange(100)
        y1 = 2*x
        y2 = 3*x**3
        self.curve_1 = pg.PlotDataItem(
            x, y1, pen=pg.mkPen(pg.mkColor((70,70,30))),
            width=4 # , clickable = True   <-- This don't work
        )
        self.curve_2 = pg.PlotDataItem(
            x, y2, pen=pg.mkPen(pg.mkColor((70,70,70))),
            width=4 # , clickable = True   <-- This don't work
        )
        self.curve_1.curve.setClickable(True)
        self.curve_2.curve.setClickable(True)
        self.glw.addItem(self.curve_1)
        self.glw.addItem(self.curve_2)
        # self.glw.setLogMode(False,False)
        self.glw.setLogMode(True,True)
        self.curve_1.sigClicked.connect(self.c1click)
        self.curve_2.sigClicked.connect(self.c2click)
        
    def c1click(self, ev):
        print('Curve 1 clicked')
    
    def c2click(self, ev):
        print('Curve 2 clicked')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```